# How to stop an object from losing its position when colliding with another physicbody

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

My player object always changes its position when hit by another object!
I don't want it to do that. I've tried setting `player.physicbody?.dynamic` to false but my object stops moving completely.

Answer (score 1):

you have to look at three physicsBody attribute, these are categoryBitMask, collisionBitMask & contactTestBitMask . First declare a struct like this

```
struct ColliderType {
static let Player:      UInt32 = 0
static let Destroyable: UInt32 = 0b1
static let Wall:        UInt32 = 0b10
static let Collectible: UInt32 = 0b100
static let Trigger:     UInt32 = 0b1000
static let Projectile:  UInt32 = 0b10000
static let Enemy:       UInt32 = 0b100000
static let None:        UInt32 = 0b1000000
}
```

n then play with this value in regarding node.

Comment: Thanks just changed the collisionBitMask to zero to solve this!

Comment: great :) , please accept my answer, as this will boost my reputation :p